# Using multiprocessing in python to improve Cassandra write instructions not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I was trying to improve Cassandra database write performance using multiprocessing in python as given [here](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/performance.html) but the time taken by this process has increased a lot. I want to know if I am making any mistake in the code. Posting my python code snippet. I am inserting data into two tables using two different worker methods. This is first worker

```
    def worker(daymonthyear, ts1, country, lat, lon, sma, dma, etype, version, ihl, tos_dscp, totallen, idnum, fragoff, ttl, proto, hdrchksm, sip, dip, opts, t_sp, t_dp, t_sqnum, t_acknum, t_dataoff, t_flags, t_winsz, t_chksm, t_urgptr, t_opts, p):

        cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])
        metadata = cluster.metadata
        session = cluster.connect()

        session.execute("USE db;")
        print current_process().name

        session.execute("INSERT INTO db.day (daymonthyear, ts, c_country, c_lat, c_lon, e_sma, e_dma, e_etype, ip_version, ip_ihl, ip_tos_dscp, ip_totallen, ip_idnum, ip_fragoff, ip_ttl, ip_proto, ip_hdrchksm, ip_sip, ip_dip, ip_opts, s_sp, s_dp, s_vtag, s_chksm) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);",(str(daymonthyear), int(ts1), str(country), str(lat), str(lon), str(sma), str(dma), str(etype), str(version), str(ihl), str(tos_dscp), int(totallen), int(idnum), str(fragoff), int(ttl), int(proto), str(hdrchksm), str(sip), str(dip), str(opts), int(s_sp), int(s_dp), int(s_vtag), str(s_chksm)))

        session.cluster.shutdown()
        session.shutdown()
```

Second worker:

```
    def worker1(monthyear, ts1, country, lat, lon, sma, dma, etype, version, ihl, tos_dscp, totallen, idnum, fragoff, ttl, proto, hdrchksm, sip, dip, opts, t_sp, t_dp, t_sqnum, t_acknum, t_dataoff, t_flags, t_winsz, t_chksm, t_urgptr, t_opts, p):

        cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])
        metadata = cluster.metadata
        session = cluster.connect()
        session.execute("USE db;")
        print current_process().name
        session.execute("INSERT INTO db.month (monthyear, ts, c_country, c_lat, c_lon, e_sma, e_dma, e_etype, ip_version, ip_ihl, ip_tos_dscp, ip_totallen, ip_idnum, ip_fragoff, ip_ttl, ip_proto, ip_hdrchksm, ip_sip, ip_dip, ip_opts, u_sp, u_dp, u_len, u_chksm) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);",(str(monthyear), int(ts1), str(country), str(lat), str(lon), str(sma), str(dma), str(etype), str(version), str(ihl), str(tos_dscp), int(totallen), int(idnum), str(fragoff), int(ttl), int(proto), str(hdrchksm), str(sip), str(dip), str(opts), int(u_sp), int(u_dp), int(u_len), str(u_chksm)))

        session.cluster.shutdown()
        session.shutdown()
```

Calling method:

```
def dump():

    for ts1,buf in pcap:
        if ip.p == dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_TCP:
            res = pool.apply_async(worker, args=(daymonthyear, ts1, country, lat, lon, sma, dma, etype, version, ihl, tos_dscp, totallen, idnum, fragoff, ttl, proto, hdrchksm, sip, dip, opts, t_sp, t_dp, t_sqnum, t_acknum, t_dataoff, t_flags, t_winsz, t_chksm, t_urgptr, t_opts, process_n,))
            res.wait()
            res = pool.apply_async(worker1, args=(monthyear, ts1, country, lat, lon, sma, dma, etype, version, ihl, tos_dscp, totallen, idnum, fragoff, ttl, proto, hdrchksm, sip, dip, opts, t_sp, t_dp, t_sqnum, t_acknum, t_dataoff, t_flags, t_winsz, t_chksm, t_urgptr, t_opts, process_n,))
            res.wait()
        if type(ip.data) == UDP :
            res = pool.apply_async(worker, args=(daymonthyear, ts1, country, lat, lon, sma, dma, etype, version, ihl, tos_dscp, totallen, idnum, fragoff, ttl, proto, hdrchksm, sip, dip, opts, t_sp, t_dp, t_sqnum, t_acknum, t_dataoff, t_flags, t_winsz, t_chksm, t_urgptr, t_opts, process_n,))
            res.wait()
            res = pool.apply_async(worker1, args=(monthyear, ts1, country, lat, lon, sma, dma, etype, version, ihl, tos_dscp, totallen, idnum, fragoff, ttl, proto, hdrchksm, sip, dip, opts, t_sp, t_dp, t_sqnum, t_acknum, t_dataoff, t_flags, t_winsz, t_chksm, t_urgptr, t_opts, process_n,))
            res.wait()
```

All the variables used are declared and there is no error in the code. The only problem is that it takes much more time than executing the insert statement sequentially in the dump method. Can anyone tell if I am using multiprocessing in the right way or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting to Cassandra is very expansive. If you connect from each process, you are spending more resources. This is especially evident when the number of processes increases. Making N connections (for a large N) is like DoSing yourself in principle.

Comment: ...and connections/sessions can't be shared between processes. .and using multithreading will be just a waste of time with python driver, as it brings any sort of problem.
https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/performance.html